# Dreamweaver cs6 Spry validation

Tags: validation, dreamweaver, spry

I have a textfield and a spry validation text field.
In the spry properties I changed the max chars value to 50, checked required and on blurr.

When I test the page I get all the error messages at once ("valure required", "exceeded max number of chars")and the textfield is not coloured. Looks good in the preview in dreamweaver.. but when I run itt in the browser it fails.
Any hints?

--FIXED--

I did not copy the spry assets folder to the testing server.. I only had it in my local site folder.

Comment: Hint: Dont use Spry. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with the error messages, it is extremely frustrating. I eventually found a solution via http://cssmenumaker.com/dreamweaver-css-menu-extension - I would definitely recommend them.

Comment: Can you please summarize the contents of the link?  Simply posting a link is not helpful.